# Making "current" on production our new development codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

After we let someone go today they nuked the repo and we can no longer access the code on their computer, to make matters worse, the backup of their machine failed. I have a copy of the production site on our production server. I downloaded "current" directory from production, what do I need to do now to make this my local development version? I have been able to get the code to run but I can't see assets when I run the "current" on my local development. I am guessing it's in production mode right now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try making it in development mode?

Comment: Guru, how do you make it in development mode? I set the RAILS_ENV=development and still no CSS/images are loading

Comment: Do you have asset files under app/assets folder ? And can you check in Firebug or by view source, what path it is trying to load assets from?